# AVPlayerLayer's frame size update in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, avfoundation

I have a view which asynchronously loads a video and presents it via another `UIViewRepresentable` view. `GeometryReader` provides the video container's frame which is then used to initialize an `AVPlayerLayer`. A problem arises when the device orientation is changed (thus, the container's frame is changed too), and `AVPlayerLayer` doesn't relayout itself to match the container. I tried to update the layer's frame within `updateUIView`, even call `setNeedsLayout` and `setNeedsDisplay` to both the layer and `uiView`, but nothing changed.

How to adapt the layer to match the size of the container?

```
struct VideoView: View {

    @StateObject var videoLoader: VideoLoader

    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        if let player = videoLoader.player {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                let frame = geometry.frame(in: .local)
                VideoPlayerView(frame: frame, player: player)
                    .frame(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
                    .onAppear { player.play() }
                    .onDisappear { player.pause() }
            }
        }
    }

}

struct VideoPlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {

    private let frame: CGRect
    private let playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer

    init(frame: CGRect, player: AVPlayer) {
        self.frame = frame
        self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        self.playerLayer.frame = frame
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let container = UIView()
        container.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        return container
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        playerLayer.frame.size = uiView.frame.size
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create a custom `UIView` and update the layer's frame size in `layoutSubviews()`.

```
struct VideoPlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {

    class PlayerContainer: UIView {

        init(playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer) {
            super.init(frame: .zero)
            layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        }

        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            layer.sublayers?.first?.frame = frame
        }

    }

    private let playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer

    init(player: AVPlayer) {
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return PlayerContainer(playerLayer: playerLayer)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) { }

}
```